# DGPS data and concerns about WGS84 accuracy

Tags: wgs84, dgps

I am using a DGPS unit to collect data points at an average accuracy of about 30 cm using QField. My data layers are in WGS84, which, I believe has a much more limited accuracy (QGIS tells me about ± 2m).

Does this mean that the data collected by the DGPS is actually much less accurate than the 30 cm indicated by the device during data collection, more on the order of ± 2 m and could reprojecting the layers at this stage make any difference to the accuracy?

Comment: Wait, where does *QGIS* assert that WGS84 is only accurate to 2m?

Comment: The [Tour] emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Presenting a bullet list of questions is likely to generate close votes.

Comment: @Vince see this tweet by Nyall Dawson: https://twitter.com/nyalldawson/status/1390118738251317254 - this warning is included in newer QGIS versions.

Answer (score -1):

QGIS - SRTM data  is 1 Arc Second accurate - 32 m approx at equator.
DGPS data will give more accurate result depending upon how far apart  data are taken
(Ofcourse the major error such as ephemeris, clock errors etc are minimal)  .